# Jquery Show não funciona em td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```js
$(".item2").hide();

$("#show").chick(function(){
 $(".item2").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>Item1</td>
  <td class="item2">Item2</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="show" id="show" />
```

Perceba que ao clicar no botão o `item2` deveria ser exibido, mas não tem funcionado. Por que isso ocorre e como resolver?

Answer (score 3):

Seu erro está aqui: `$("#show").chick(function(){` *`"chick"`* o correto é `click`.

```js
$(".item2").hide();

$("#show").click(function(){
 $(".item2").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>Item1</td>
  <td class="item2">Item2</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="show" id="show" />
```

Comment: @jedaiasrodrigues Por favor revisar o código antes!

Answer (score 3):

Você estava usando .chick ao invés de click.
Tenta agora.

```js
$(".item2").hide();

$("#show").click(function(){
 $(".item2").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>Item1</td>
  <td class="item2">Item2</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="show" id="show" />
```